# How I reduce memory consumption in a loop in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow

I have a loop in TensorFlow that looks like this:

```
with tf.device("/gpu:1"):
    losses = []

    for target, output in zip(targets, lstm_outputs):
        logits = tf.matmul(W, output) + b
        loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, target)
        losses.append(loss)

    total_loss = tf.add_n(losses)
```

I am getting an OOM error when allocating the gradients for this layer, since each matrix multiplication is a different operation in the graph taking memory. Is there a way of preventing TensorFlow from allocating all these operations at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a challenging graph for TensorFlow to optimize, since the activations from each layer must be kept to aggregate a single gradient for `W`. One possibility is to pass the [experimental](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0249729a26b2cd3bdbbc5880f8d634a56860b0fd/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py#L580) `aggregation_method` argument when calling [`optimizer.optimize()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.minimize).

For example, you could try the following:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(...)  # Or another optimization algorithm.
train_op = optimizer.minimize(
    total_loss,
    aggregation_method=tf.AggregationMethod.EXPERIMENTAL_ACCUMULATE_N)
```

This option eagerly aggregates the gradients for recurrently-used variables in place, rather than keeping them all in memory until all of the gradients have been computed. If this doesn't work, the `tf.AggregationMethod.EXPERIMENTAL_TREE` may work better.

Comment: I already tried those two EXPERIMENTAL_ACCUMULATE_N and EXPERIMENTAL_TREE to no avail. I will try using a while loop.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue, by updating from the stable release to master in combination with using EXPERIMENTAL_ACCUMULATE_N. @mrry thanks for your efforts and responsiveness.