# Why does Tensorflow CNN use too much memory?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution, data-science

I'm new to deep learning and I'm using Tensorflow train a cnn to do image recognition. The training images are all 128 pixels * 128 pixels * 3 channels. In my network, there are 3 conv layers, 3 maxpooling layers and 1 fully connected layers. I have more than 180,000 labeled images so I decided to train 4000 images each batch. However, the training process can not even run on my laptop because the memory is not enough so I tried to use a sever with 64gb ram and 2 * E5 CPU to train it. This time it works, but costs more than 40GB of memory.
I'm confused that the images I used for training are not high resolution images(only 128*128). But why still costs too much memory(may be the batch size it too big....). Is this normal? If this is normal, how could people use gpu to train neural networks, as far as i know, gtx1080ti has 11GB memory, but still not enough for training my network.

Comment: it is hard to estimate the memory without the full architecture. however, 4000 batch size is huge; the input size alone would be 4000 image per batch * (128*128) pixel per image *3 channel per pixel * 4 byte per channel  = 786432000 bytes = 0.732421875 GB (assuming your network uses tf.float32) which is huge. the full network would be much larger since each layer needs to cache the inputs for the back propagation step during training.

Comment: @Yahia Zakaria  Thank you for your analysis.  I do can reduce the batch size to reduce memory usage whice means much more batches and time to converge. Is this the only choice?

Comment: Sometimes this is the only choice. In some cases, the network itself can be optimized (some operations can be replaced with other more efficient choices or combined operations). Sometimes, picking a different aggregation_method in the optimizer.minimize can help (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194394/how-i-reduce-memory-consumption-in-a-loop-in-tensorflow). However, if all fails, then decreasing batch size may be the only choice.

Answer (score 3):

4000 sounds like a lot in one go. Most examples I've seen train a few hundred in each batch. I imagine that all the images may be getting loaded into memory at once, hence the high memory usage.

Can you try training with smaller batches? 1000, or even 500, and see if the memory usage drops?

Answer (score 1):

For TensorFlow will store the middle value(gradients between layers for example) of the computing for BP, so the larger size of the input the more memory it consumes. So reduce your batch size is the fast way to reduce the memory usage.

Comment: Reducing the batch can really reduce the memory usage, but since the are too many labled training data. It will need so much more batches to run through all the training data which means much more time to converge. Is the the only way to reduce memory usage?